# IE 9/10/11 sound file limit

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-audio

I'm making a browser game which have about 60 various-length audio files playing on the same scene, and thus cannot be unloaded.

I wonder if someone is facing this problem except me: IE has a (hardware dependent) limit of sound files that can be loaded via HTML5 Audio.load method. In my case it's  exactly 41 sound file. When reaching this limit, IE fails to load sound with onerrror event firing on Audio element (I'm not making a testcase, hoping that it's a well-known bug, so many years it's there).

So, what can be done with this? Sound sprites? Tried that one, every browser except IE is OK playing sound sprites, but in IE there are some problems (as always). What else?

Thank you!

Comment: Found this shortly after posting [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939006/ie-9-and-10-yield-unexpected-and-inconsistent-mediaerrors). ... Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still a problem for me.

Comment: If you don't need 41 or more channels playing simultaneously, you can recycle audio objects.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case each sound must be played instantly, without any delay, thus must be preloaded somehow.

Comment: If you're setting `Expires` headers, you can probably preload them in hidden `img` tags, AJAX requests, or cycling them through a designated "preloader" `audio` tag. ... As long as your `Expires` header is set for "a long time from now", IE should hold onto them.

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting idea! Thank you!